Is a utensil used to pickle meat Ben Yomo for 24 hours
According to the Talmud in Chullin 97b pickling is considered cooking in Halacha.
My question is, does this only mean the food has the halachic status of being cooked? Or does this Gemara also mean the utensil used to pickle the meat is treated as Ben Yomo for 24 hours (which for Basar B’chalav/Issur V’heter means you have to wait 24 hours before kashering) like it would be if it were used to cook meat through heat?

The issue is more than ben yomo, the utensil actually absorbs taste and needs to be kashered, see my answer. I don't know if this is what you meant to ask and didn't want to edit your question further without checking.

It's similar to cooking but since there is no hear involved kovesh is not treat the same way as cooking in all cases. For example basar b'chalav is prohibited on a Torah level when cooking is involved which requires heat but if they are mixed together through kovesh and there is a safek that the specific liquid did not reach the full amount of time to be kovesh then it would not be considered basar b'chalav

You are speaking of the law of kavush ke-mevushal, pickling, and the halacha (YD 105) is that taste transfers even at cold when food is left immersed/soaking in a liquid for 24 hours or longer (and much faster for sharp foods, 6-18 minutes), similarly to the situation where it would have been cooked in the liquid. For instance, leaving milk together with a meat food for 24 hours renders both foods forbidden.
In this case, the utensil is forbidden as well and needs hagala. R Pinchas Cohen (in Laws of Kashrut p. 9) writes this does not apply to glass (NB: outside of Pesach where we are strict, see also here).
R Binyomin Forst (The kosher kitchen, pp. 77ff) writes poskim disagree whether this applies only to earthenware and other porous materials (e.g., stone) or to metals as well. He agrees this doesn't apply to glass outside of Pesach.
Traditionally one waits 24 hours before performing hagala, but if one needs to kasher the utensil before 24 hours, one can simply add soap to the kashering water.
See also Hebrew footnotes to Peninei Halacha Kashrut 35:9
